# Optimizing Vertex Shaders

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metalkit

I am passing these datas to Vertex Shader. In the Image You can see the size is every time 0.024 not changing but Every time I am passing that value. Anyway to send only once to the shader. [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a separate buffer to the vertex shader. It would be a single value (or struct), not an array. You'd receive it in the shader parameters with something like:

```
    ..., constant MyStruct &my_param [[buffer(2)]], ...
```

and use it in the body with:

```
... my_param.size_or_whatever_field ...
```